# How do I launch this .plist file on startup *before* I log in?

Tags: macos, mac, boot, osx-mountain-lion, launchctl

*I copied the current full `.plist` file at the bottom of this question.*

Right now I have a `.plist` file that I loaded with `launchctl -w load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.setgetscreenres.plist` to make my OS X run at 2880x1800 (retina) resolution on start-up and this works fine.

However, I don't really know how to control the order of `.plist` files in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and sometimes it will take up to a minute before the `setgetscreenres` command runs after logging in. Therefore I would like to run this command *before* I log in, like how iStat does.

I understand that I need to move the `.plist.` file to `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `chown root:wheel`, and run `sudo launchctl -w load`, but that didn't work. Now I'm thinking there is something wrong/missing in my `.plist` XML.

Is there something I need to add extra in order to run as `root` or launch from `/Library/LaunchAgents`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.setgetscreenres</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/hobbes3/Code/setgetscreenres</string>
        <string>2880</string>
        <string>1800</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need `launchctl load -w`. If you save this plist as `/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist` and it's owned by root, it should be loaded automatically on login:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>say</string>
        <string>a</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I tried saving another plist like that in the user library, the say commands overlapped though.

If LimitLoadToSessionType is set to LoginWindow, the program is run when the graphical login window is shown:

```
<key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
<string>LoginWindow</string>
```

It is not run at all if automatic login is enabled though.

Comment: That worked but I ended up not running the `.plist` as root because as soon as I log in, Mac resize the resolution to the "Scaled: Most space" setting on the user. Is there an option to make the user `.plist` load before all other `.plist`?

Comment: I think I got it with `<key>Nice</key><integer>-20</integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that is stored in ~ (your home folders) starts up or loads as soon as you log into your user. So if u want to start something at boot, you might want to have a look at the root library, so /Library/LauchAgents for your launchagents for example.

Comment: I put that .plist in `/Library/LaunchAgents` and the command didn't run on bootup.